# Generate runtime warning when package is required

Tags: emacs, warnings

I'd like to generate a warning when a library is loaded at runtime similar to how `cl-lib` used to do (it doesn't seem to as of v27).

How is this implemented?  Does it have something something like `(run-hooks 'cl-macs-load-hook)` from `cl-macs`?

Also, `cl` now generates a message saying it is deprecated, but I don't see any macro to define an obsolete package -- is this implemented similarly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ AFAIK there's never been such a warning for `cl-lib`, you're probably confusing it with the warning for `cl`.  ]

There's `with-eval-after-load` for that.  E.g.

```
(with-eval-after-load 'that-nasty-lib
  (message "BEWARE, 'that-nasty-lib' has just been loaded!"))
```